# WPF Dynamic UserControl Style At Runtime

Tags: wpf

I have a user control with a togglebutton and a couple of textblocks/labels.  I have two styles in my xaml for the toggle button style.  I add these usercontrols dynamically when my form loads.  I want to be able to apply different styles at runtime in my application.  I can't quite figure out how to do this.  Here is my user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="122" Width="170" BorderThickness="1"> 
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Test2" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="border" Background="Magenta"  BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Gainsboro"/>


                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="Test3" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="border" Background="Beige"  BorderBrush="#FFF30808" BorderThickness="4,4,4,4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="Gainsboro"/>


                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
   </UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Margin="0,0,10,10">
    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" d:DesignHeight="133" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:DesignWidth="172" Margin="0,0,-11,-10">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="btnUserButton"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:DesignWidth="229" d:DesignHeight="101" ClipToBounds="true" Width="166" Height="100" Click="onButtonClick" Background="#FFA29E9E" Style="{StaticResource Test2}" >
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Title" d:DesignFontSize="35" d:DesignHeight="40" d:DesignWidth="201" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"  ClipToBounds="true" FontSize="30"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Body" d:DesignFontSize="35" d:DesignHeight="40" d:DesignWidth="201" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="cavityNumber"  ClipToBounds="true" FontSize="30"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToggleButton>
        <Label x:Name="lblYield" Content="Label"  VerticalAlignment="Top" d:DesignWidth="106" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" d:DesignFontSize="20" d:DesignHeight="38"  ClipToBounds="true" Width="81" />
        <Label x:Name="lblScrap" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red"  ClipToBounds="true" Width="76"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

I have added a 'style' property to my control, but I don't know if I need it or what to do with it.

```
    Property thestyle() As Style
    Get
        Return mystyle
    End Get
    Set(value As Style)
        mystyle = value
        btnUserButton.Style = mystyle
    End Set
End Property
```

What I would like to do is somehow access styles 'Test2' and 'Test3' at runtime.  These styles will be based off of a user selection.

```
MyUserControl.Style = DirectCast(FindResource("Test2"), Style)
```

That, of course, does not work.  I read on here about application resources, but I am not sure how to incorporate that into my usercontrol.  Anyway, thanks for any help you can give me on this...it's quite confusing being I am somewhat new to WPF.  Thanks, again.

Comment: If your styling is all about `ContentTemplate`, I recommend you to read about `ContentTemplateSelector`, eg: http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/using-contenttemplateselector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the easiest and best way is to use resources. To use resources in your app, first create a `xaml` file somewhere in your project. Call it `Styles` This will be a place where you can dump all your styles, you can then re use them on different usercontrols/grids etc.

**Styles.xaml**

Inside the xaml resources file, add a style. It should look similar to this:

```
    <ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation">

        <!-- LayoutRoot Grid Style (Example Style) -->
        <Style x:Key="LayoutRootGridStyle" TargetType="Grid">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
```

---

**App.xaml**

Then in your App.xaml/Application.xaml, you must add a reference to this new resource dictionary.

For example inside App.xaml:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

---

Now you can use the styles that you create in the resource dictionary.

***You can use them in the code behind by:***

```
Dim st As Style = TryCast(Application.Current.Resources("MyButtonStyle"), Style)

myButton.Style = st
```

***Or directly in the XAML by:***

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource MyStyleName}" />
```

Comment: Ok, sorry, having trouble understanding this.  I added the Style.xaml to my main project and then attempted to apply style 'Test2' to my usercontrol that I brought in.  The style is for a toggle button so when I try to apply it says that it's not valid since I am applying it to my user control.  Sorry, I am very confused.  Here is the exact error: Additional information: 'ToggleButton' TargetType does not match type of element 'UserControl1'.

Comment: ok so apply each style to the toggle button instead of the user control. For example btnUserButton.Style = TryCast(Application.Current.Resources("Test2"), Style)

Comment: Ok, another dumb question.  How do I expose the controls within my usercontrol?  I created the usercontrol (dll) then dropped it into a window of another project.  I can't seem to get to the btnUserButton control from within my new window. I can only see UserControl1.  Sorry about this - maybe I should go back to winforms.

Comment: You should be able to get to it in the codebehind of your Usercontrol1. `Usercontrol1.vb` If you're wanting to access it from another class, then create an instance of `Usercontrol1` then access the button there. e.g. `Dim uc1 as new Usercontrol1` `uc1.btnUserButton`

Comment: And no, stick with it! in my opinion WPF is way better than winforms. Once you get to grip with how the XAML works and integrates with the code - it becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I wasn't instantiating the control.  It is working perfectly.

Comment: Funny thing is I probably wouldn't have needed to ask this question if I had just done the 'as new usercontrol'.  But, then again, I would not have learned how to do the resource thing either - which is invaluable.  Thanks, again for your time and help.